# SSL issue with cURL after moving to a new server

Tags: php, security, curl, ssl, https

I'm using cURL to send some data using `CURLOPT_POST`. Same code was working fine before but after moving to a new server cURL is not working anymore via `https`. The guys from the other site (`domain.com`) sent me the log files and nothing was received by them. Then I tried to get an error with `curl_error()` and I was faced with a SSL problem but don't know how to fix it.

Code:

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://track.domain.com/api.php'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param); 
curl_exec($ch);
$error = curl_error($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
```

The error is:

```
SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

I searched for this on Google but couldn't understand what the problem is.

Do I need SSL certificate for our domain? I'm not sure if there was SSL in the old server. Is you can see from the code, I don't need return. So, should I have SSL, too, in this case?

Do I need `domain.com`'s certificate?

Do I need contacting the hosting company for recompiling cURL with SSL support?

Any ideas?

---

***Note:*** I don't want a workaround by setting `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` and `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST` to `false`.

---

**curl_version():**

```
Array
(
    [version_number] => 464896
    [age] => 3
    [features] => 34333
    [ssl_version_number] => 0
    [version] => 7.24.0
    [host] => i686-pc-linux-gnu
    [ssl_version] => OpenSSL/0.9.8b
    [libz_version] => 1.2.3
    [protocols] => Array
        (
            [0] => dict
            [1] => file
            [2] => ftp
            [3] => ftps
            [4] => gopher
            [5] => http
            [6] => https
            [7] => imap
            [8] => imaps
            [9] => pop3
            [10] => pop3s
            [11] => rtsp
            [12] => smtp
            [13] => smtps
            [14] => telnet
            [15] => tftp
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

downloaded Mozilla's [bundle](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html) file, named it `mozilla.pem`

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,true); 
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CAINFO,'mozilla.pem');
```

The issue is your CA (Certificate Authority) list doesn't have the issuer of the remote site certificate. This method will not fix if your trying to connect to a server who has a self singed certificate.

Comment: Should I do this myself or it's better to contact the hosting company?

Comment: you can do it your self, this is user configurable space.

Comment: My site doesn't have SSL at all. The other site has. I'm sending the data like "send and forget", i.e. without needing some return. Do both sides need SLL in this case?

Comment: client certificates are needed when server requests it, so i am guessing since this worked in the previous hosting company your just missing the `CA` file which i gave u where to download from.

Comment: Hum, it's working with this file. But it's a little bit confusing. I never had seen a `.pem` file in the ftp. And I have to call this file on every cURL request which is strange. Should I contact the host to add this bundle by default somehow?

Comment: if its working you can at least accept the answer first right :) i will give you more detail explanation about it, i have to go now

Comment: Yep, it solved the problem but seems like a workaround. I never used `CURLOPT_CAINFO` before, so there should be a permanent solution to this. I will be very happy if you can explain how to make cURL working as on the old server. :)